# Simple logistic regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I tried to solve a simple linear regression problem of two-dimensional classification.
Here I have a feature matrix X_expanded, which has a shape of [826,6]. To classify objects we will obtain probability of object belongs to class '1'. To predict probability we will use output of linear model and logistic function.
And here is the function of compute probability.

```
def probability(X, w):
    """
    Given input features and weights
    return predicted probabilities of y==1 given x, P(y=1|x), see description above

    Don't forget to use expand(X) function (where necessary) in this and subsequent functions.

    :param X: feature matrix X of shape [n_samples,6] (expanded)
    :param w: weight vector w of shape [6] for each of the expanded features
    :returns: an array of predicted probabilities in [0,1] interval.
    """

    # TODO:<your code here>
    X = X_expanded
    m = X.shape[0]
    w = np.zeros((m,1))
    Z = np.dot(w.T,X)
    P = 1./(1+np.exp(-Z))

    return P
```

For a simple test:

```
dummy_weights = np.linspace(-1, 1, 6)
ans_part1 = probability(X_expanded[:1, :], dummy_weights)[0]
```

But it always returns `array([ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5])`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: w = np.zeros((m,1)) returns array of zeros, Z = np.dot(w.T,X) will always return 0.So P = 1./(1+np.exp(0)) will be always 0.5.

Comment: So how should I initialize the weights vector?

Comment: np.random.rand(m, 1)

Answer (score 1):

Since you've initialized your weights as zeros, Z = np.dot(w.T,X) will be 0 and the sigmoid function would return 0.5 always. You need a random initialization of weights. It can be done by :

```
dummy_weights = np.random.rand(m, 1)
```